# Create concept vector from ontology

Tags: ontology, triplestore, cosine-similarity, owl-api, triples

I have a set of  documents pertaining to a domain. The data in those documents can be conceptually mapped to a domain ontology. I need to find similarity scores between those docs. In literature, many have proposed to create a vector of concepts(similar to term vector) and then use cosine law to calculate similarity.

I know how to create a term vector/tf-idf vector for a document.

For Example:
Lets say i have two documents describing two user profiles.
After tokenizing and stemming i have two bag of words for each doc.
Doc1: (tom,yahoo)
Doc2: (jerry,google)
These bag of words can be represented by a tf-idf vector for each document.
The cosine similarity score in this case would be zero as its only based on the exact word being present.

But the knowledge that both yahoo and google are search engines and that both users use search engines is captured in the ontology. 
**Yahoo** "***is-a***" **search engine**.
*Yahoo* and **search engine** as concepts is present in ontology and is-a is the relationship that joins these concepts.
I want to use these concepts and create a vector for cosine law.
But i have no idea how to extract a vector/bag of concepts from the ontology.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: What are the vectors supposed to be? Can you give an example? There are lots of ways you can make a vector from an ontology, but it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

This is only one way of creating vectors, as you are unsure of what you need. First, you need to use an api such as [OWL-API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net) to access the information within an ontology. By what you are suggesting you both need to extract modelling elements, e.g. classes, individual, and properties. In your case `yahoo` might be an individual and `search engine` might be a class. So you want to be able to extract them. If you need OWL-API examples, just look at other stack overflow questions, or read the examples on the linked website.

Then you need to extract the axioms for example `yahoo is a search engine`. Then if you are calculating frequencies, you just can treat them as sentences and calculate the frequency of whatever you require. There is whole field of calculating semantic similarity or syntactical similarities in ontologies. Open google scholar and search for them.